# Parameter beego swagger to send HTTP requset

Tags: go, swagger, beego

Fairly new to beego and Go in general, but this seems more like a config problem.

When I run my beego server with `bee run` (I use the options `-downdoc=true -gendoc=true` but the same happens without them), the generated swagger that I acces through localhost:[my_app_port]/swagger/ presents two problems :

- The requests sent by the swagger use HTTPS and return a 400 code since the server doesn't have an HTTPS listener
- Less important, the petshop swagger is always displayed first, I have to edit the address in the URL search to swagger.json to the swagger for my app.

Has this ever happened to someone else, and how did you solve it ? The internet seems to lack a reel beego community and I can't find a post with similar experience.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : after a fair amount of searching, this stems from the -downdoc command. It has been reported [in a ticket](https://github.com/beego/swagger/pull/13) that index.html was generated with the link to petstore rather than swagger.json. However, the change doesn't seem to be effective.